# Understanding The Equations Behind Dual Objects In Monoidal Categories

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra, monoidal-categories

I think about the identities in monoidal categories $C$ (triangle and pentagon) the following way:  Let $\Sigma=(\otimes,1)$ denote the monoid signature, $T(\Sigma,C_0)$ the set of terms over $\Sigma$ with objects from $C$ as variables and $\epsilon$ the evaluation map from terms to objects.  Then, to any equivalent terms $s\sim t$ in $T(\Sigma,C_0)$ we can assign an isomorphism $f_{s,t}:\epsilon(s)\rightarrow\epsilon(t)$ such that for $s\sim t\sim u$ we have $f_{t,u}\circ f_{s,t}=f_{s,u}$.  The triangle and pentagon identities form a kind of locally finite generator set for these isomorphism.

The definition of units and counits looks similar at first glance to the the definition of associators and unitors, however, our maps are not necessarily isomorphisms this time.  So I wondered, does a similar finite generator set approach exist for the equations behind dual objects?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Aren't the triangle identities a finite generating set for the identities satisfied by the unit and counit, by definition?

Comment: @KevinCarlson Maybe I'm confused!  I mean, sure, the triangle identities generate a larger set of identities, but is there a nice description of this whole set analogously to the case of associators and unitors as described above?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In a sense, it seems you're looking for a description of the free monoidal category with an object that has a dual. This is related to the free 2-category with an adjunction, which is studied in detail in various places, but it's not quite the same thing, as the objects in the monoidal category can be tensored with themselves. So I don't know what's known here. This kind of question fits generally into the subject of coherence theory. You might check the references at Kelly-Maclane graph on the nLab.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thank you!  Similar question, can I think about these equation the way that whenever I get from $x$ to $y$ using only associators, unitors, units and counits (or sometimes called evaluations and coevaluations), the resulting arrow $f:x\rightarrow y$ is always the same?

Comment: Unfortunately, not quite. There are natural maps $k:a\to a^{**}$ as well as $[k,\mathrm{id}_a]:a^{***}\to a^*$. In a category of vector spaces, $k$ is the usual embedding in the double dual. One knows that this is not an isomorphism when $a$ is infinite-dimensional, and so the arrows $k_{a^*}\circ [k,\mathrm{id}_a],\mathrm{id}_{a^{***}}:a^{***}\to a^{***}$ are not, generally, equal. This example is from the Kelly-Maclane paper referenced on the page I linked you to, where they also describe which diagrams do commute.